# Null pointer is not supported here

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

profile.java

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvEmail;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_profile );
        tvEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEmailProfile);
        tvEmail.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Email"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: You probably should check if there is such a thing as "Email" in your intent extras, like  `if(getIntent().hasExtra("Email")){...}`

Comment: A null pointer is NEVER supported.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there is no extra with the name "Email" in your intent and you should check that before trying to set it in your TextView:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_profile );
        tvEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEmailProfile);
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("Email")){
            tvEmail.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Email"));
        }
    }
}
```

This will solve the NullPointer problem. But you should check if the key "Email" is really what you are looking for.